# Jquery - Ensure all checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a JS function that will ensure all checkboxes in my form are selected.

I have tried the following, but it isn't working. There are other checkboxes in another from on this page so I am wondering if this is conflicting? I thought using $(this) would fix that issue...

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checked = false;
    $('#input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checked = true;
        }
    });

    if (checked == false) {
        console.log('Something wasnt checked');
    }
});
```

Can any advise what I am doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"#" is used to query elements by their ID, so $("#input") would target only one input that has id="input". You should instead do this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']")
```

or, if you don't want all checkboxes on the page you will need to use some other selector, etc. add class "some-class" to all inputs that you want to check and use:

```
$(".some-class")
```

Also, you will need to revert your logic, cause currently you will set checked to true if any of the checkboxes is checked. So, initially use checked = true, then in if statement set it to false if it's not checked.

Comment: Thanks, I added the classes and updated the login, here is my working example for anyone following this https://jsfiddle.net/qLur7zxf/4/

Answer (score 2):

Your code checks if any of the checkboxes are checked.

Change the code to

```
var checked = true;
```

And set the variable to false, if the checkbox in the loop is NOT checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just check `:checked` checkbox `length` based upon that set your variable like below.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  var checked = false;
  if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == $('input[type="checkbox"]').length)
    checked = true;

  if (checked == true)
    console.log('checked');
  else
    console.log('false');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```